# Does Google App Engine allow importing external Github repository when using Go?

Tags: git, google-app-engine, go, repository, google-app-engine-go

For example, if I created a web application with Go, am I able to import the following Git repository that is listed in my Go code below:

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
    )

    func main() {
        excelFileName := "/home/tealeg/foo.xlsx"
        xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFileName)
        if err != nil {
            ...
        }
        for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
            for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
                for _, cell := range row.Cells {
                    text, _ := cell.String()
                    fmt.Printf("%s\n", text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it? The docs also mention it: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-go-libraries

Comment: Thank you for the link @WiredPrairie. The "go get github..." part became useful once I figured out how to use cloud shell and how it works with the google cloud repository. I assumed once it was in the repository, the cloud shell cant access it. Totally wrong and took me hours to figure out. My project is now able to build and use xlsx by tealeg.